# Is it possible to 'Paste Without Formatting' in MS Lync?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, lync, lync-2010

I use a Dark Theme in Visual Studios, and if I copy a snippet of code and paste it into Lync it saves the formatting of the font itself-- so I get a bunch of white font on a white background.

I have to go and paste it into Notepad, then copy that and paste again into Lync. Very tedious. I was hoping someone might know of a solution whether it be in VS or Lync? I've been searching through the Extension 'store' for VS trying to find something like this but I haven't had any luck...

Comment: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594640/CopyplusandplusPasteplusFormattingpluswithplusVisu) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The combination to paste without format is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

I haven't tried it on Lync but usually runs well on Windows platform.